# Kubernetes Nginx Ingress Controller Metrics

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, metrics, prometheus, ingress

I've tried to find a documentation about the metrics exposed by the NGINX ingress controller in Kubernetes but so far I haven't found any reliable source about the metrics and what they mean.

For example, there are three different `request_size` metrics (`sum`, `bucket`, `count`).

From my guessing `sum` and `count` correlate with each other. And to get the average request size I could probably do something like `sum by (method) (request_size_sum{...}) / sum by (method) (request_size_count{...})`.

But what about `bucket` and especially what is `le`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For metrics itself and some explanations about them, I think the closest and full list is presented on [Github issue - Document prometheus metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/2924)

Note! This is about ingress nginx which is kubernetes community driven. Ingress nginx which is developed by nginx inc is a different project so there can be some differences.

---

As for the types of metrics, this is about `Prometheus` itself. There are different types of them:

- [**counter**](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter):

  > A counter is a cumulative metric that represents a single
  > monotonically increasing counter whose value can only increase or be
  > reset to zero on restart. For example, you can use a counter to
  > represent the number of requests served, tasks completed, or errors.
- [**gauge**](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#gauge):

  > A gauge is a metric that represents a single numerical value that can
  > arbitrarily go up and down.
  >
  > Gauges are typically used for measured values like temperatures or
  > current memory usage, but also "counts" that can go up and down, like
  > the number of concurrent requests.
- [**histogram**](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#histogram) (it's about buckets):

  > A histogram samples observations (usually things like request
  > durations or response sizes) and counts them in configurable buckets.
  > It also provides a sum of all observed values.
- [**summary**](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#summary):

  > Similar to a histogram, a summary samples observations (usually things
  > like request durations and response sizes). While it also provides a
  > total count of observations and a sum of all observed values, it
  > calculates configurable quantiles over a sliding time window.

Please also get familiar with [histograms and summaries](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/histograms/).

As for `le`:

> `le` is the canonical abbreviation for "less than or equal".

Find an [example of Prometheus queries and explanations](https://opstrace.com/blog/grafana-histogram-howto#2-construct-the-prometheus-query)